# Can I generate new array with another variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic

```
function construct(head, tail) {
  return cat([head], _.toArray(tail));
}
```

I'd like to know the role of '[' and ']' above.
Is it an operator?
Is it the array initialize literal?

This question is answered here and on the previous QnA([Use of [square brackets] around JavaScript variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629539/use-of-square-brackets-around-javascript-variables)).

I felt this weird because I am not used to javascript.
But this is not a matter any more.
I thought wrong and this is explained. Thanks!

Comment: I googled it for you - https://www.bing.com/search?q=javascript+what+square+brackets+mean - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629539/use-of-square-brackets-around-javascript-variables.

Comment: @Alexi Levenkov, I originally asked two questions. Previous QnA thread is ,yes, answers for my 1st question. But the other question is not answered there. You didn't googled. You bingged! *^^*

Comment: You should not ask two questions in one post. Also most languages you've mentioned allow array initialization with variable like `int[] foo = {myVariable}` - so you may want to rewrite your second question if you decide to ask separate one for that.

Comment: Side note: please avoid using quote/code formatting for coloring - if it is your own text and not quote from some other source use plain text.

Comment: @Alexi Levenkov, I agree that in C/C++ variables can be placed in the array size expression. So it is common between C/C++ and Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is initializing a 1 element array to pass to `cat` here. Brackets can be used to access elements on objects and arrays, and to represent an array literal like you have here.