# TypeScript with a variable having two names

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to understand a code written in TypeScript. I myself have a Java background and I find the syntax of the following code hard to understand. The code example is from the first [Material UI Select code example](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/):

```
const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
React.useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current!.offsetWidth);
}, []);
```

So what exaclty is done here? What is the name of the variable `const [labelWidt, setLabelWidth]`? Are these two variables or is this one variable? Like an array? Later in the code it `labelWidth` has a number that can be used to set the width of some label. Then `setLabelWidth` is used like a function that takes a param `inputLabel.current!.offsetWidth`. Where is it defined that this is a function?

Can someone please explain?

Comment: The `const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] ...` part is called "array destructuring", you can Google it to get a full explanation. In terms of what those 2 variables refer to and where `setLabelWidth` is defined, that relates to the `useState` hook. Looking into "React hooks" will show what's going on (but look up destructuring first so the declaration makes sense).

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47859541/2055998

Comment: Other than the code containing a non-null `!` assertion, the question itself has nothing to do with TypeScript

Comment: @PatrickRoberts TypeScript/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

It is an  ECMAScript 2015 feature that TypeScript has is destructuring. For a complete reference, see the article on the Mozilla Developer Network. [Destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

You can also see typescript documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Given

```
const arr = ['item1', 'item2'];
```

this

```
const [a, b] = arr;
```

is the same as

```
const a = arr[0];
const b = arr[1];
```